# Getting Exception-java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to jsp,when I try to invoke a jsp page by some parameters named cId and passWord,I getting this error,The code I have been trying is given below,I have already gone through the same error which have been seen by googling,but still I am getting the same issue.
The code is:

```
<body>
        <%

        String cidMessage = "cID";
        String passEncrypted = "passWord";
        System.out.println("CID ISSSSSSSSSSSS"+cId);
        if ((cId.equals(cidMessage)) && (passWord.equals(passEncrypted))) {
                        System.out.println("Validation Correct"+cId);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String time = sdf.format(date.getTime());
            String xmlOutput = "<smsreport>"
                    + "<date>" + time + "</date>"
                    + "<result>" + "SUCESS" + "</result>"
                    + "<msgid>" + currentTimeMillis() + "</msgid>"
                    + "<msgparts>" + "1" + "</msgparts>"
                    + "</smsreport>";

            try {
                byte[] contents = xmlOutput.getBytes();
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.setContentLength(contents.length);
                response.getOutputStream().write(contents);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }
        } else {
                           System.out.println("Validation Wrong"+cId);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String time = sdf.format(date.getTime());
            String xmlOutput = "<smsreport>"
                    + "<date>" + time + "</date>"
                    + "<result>ERROR</result>"
                    + "<msgid>" + "ErrorCode" + "</msgid>"
                    + "<msgparts>" + "ErrorMessage" + "</msgparts>"
                    + "</smsreport>";

            try {
                byte[] contents = xmlOutput.getBytes();
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.setContentLength(contents.length);
                response.getOutputStream().write(contents);
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }

        }
    %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try and do this inside a JSP. The JSP will already have obtained an output stream to write it's output. You need to use a servlet to return your XML.

When you call response.getOutputStream, it is conflicting with the fact that the JSP (which will be compiled into a servlet) already obtained an output stream. This is why it is resulting in the IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 2):

- If you check the documentation of [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) method: It mentions

**Throws**:`IllegalStateException` - if the `getWriter` method has been called on this response .

- This means that you can call either `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` methods.
- Now in JSP (*and eventually in compiled servlet*), there is an implicit variable defined called `out` . This is nothing but an instance of `PrintWriter` class. This means that on the response object, `getWriter()` is already called and hence on calling `getOutputStream()` you get `IllegalStateException`
- Now as solution for this problem, as some people have pointed out, move this code into a servlet where you have full control and use the outputstream the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSP with scriplet which is converted into a Servlet file. You dont need to call explicitly the response object. If you need to see how a compiled JSP looks like when its deployed , search (Google) how to look for the compiled class(Servlet generated out of JSP) on the server. Since you have already called the method on the response a second invocation is Illegal on the response object