# Generating Xls File Using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, xls

I need to generate xls file from jsp.

this is the code for generating the xls.

```
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
 java.io.File fn=new java.io.File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"BillSummaryReport.xls");
 if(!fn.exists()){
 fn.createNewFile();
 }
System.out.println(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"BillSummaryReport.xls");
//FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
java.io.FileInputStream fin = new java.io.FileInputStream(fn);
ServletOutputStream outStream =response.getOutputStream();
hwb.write(response.getOutputStream());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=BillSummaryReport.xls");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while ((n = fin.read(buffer)) != -1) {  
outStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
System.out.println(buffer);}
outStream.flush();
fin.close();
outStream.close();
} catch( Exception ex ) {
System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Error occurs like this when i am trying to run the application.

```
    >Sep 19, 2014 11:45:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Midrest] threw exception   [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:213)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951041/getting-exception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a jsp file which contains (writes) text to the output to send back a file (xls for example). Jsp files (which are compiled into servlets) will attempt to write to the output using `response.getWriter()`.

Since you called `response.getOutputStream()` to send your file, the jsp file (servlet) trying to call `response.getWriter()` to write HTML data will fail because only one of those 2 methods (`getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()`) can be used.

If you want to send back a file, use a simple `Servlet` for that and not a jsp file. Or if you must, you can use a jsp for this but then you can't write anything to the output, not even a line break. So best is to use a `Servlet` for this.

Comment: but its generating xls file for less contents and jsp file for large contents.